# Expected array for `items` polymer

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm learning Polymer 1.0 and I'm trying to pull weather data from an api. At the start I hardcoded the URL and I'm able to get the data since I can see it in the dev console. Now I'm trying to do a `dom-repeat` but I'm getting a weird error in the console:

`[dom-repeat::dom-repeat]: expected array for 'items', found Object {city: Object, cod: "200", message: 0.0058, cnt: 3, list: Array[3]}  polymer.html:3923`

I have my index.html that imports webcomponents and the weather.html file I'm working with. Following I'm going to paste the code of both files.

Index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

  <title>Weather</title>
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js">    </script>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/weather-forecast/weather-forecast.htm">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
 </head>
   <body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
     <weather-forecast></weather-forecast>
   </body>
 </html>
```

weather-forecast.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="weather-forecast">
    <style>
     :host{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    </style>

<template>

    <iron-ajax
        auto
        handle-as="json"
        url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=la%20vergne,us&units=imperial&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0&cnt=3"
        last-response="{{response}}">
    </iron-ajax>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}">
        <div>
            <p>{{item.list.main.temp}}</p>
            <p>{{item.city.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
</dom-module>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'weather-forecast',

    properties: {
    }
});
</script>
```

What is wrong in this code????

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the error message should get you started:

> [dom-repeat::dom-repeat]: expected array for 'items'

Which leads you to this line, as this is your dom-repeat which takes an 'items':

`<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}">`

The issue you're having is that `response` should be an array, but it isn't. From the end of the error message it looks like response is actually some JSON:

> found Object {city: Object, cod: "200", message: 0.0058, cnt: 3, list: Array[3]}

The JSON seems to contain an array though (list), so maybe this is what you need? Try updating to:

`<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response.list}}">`

Comment: handle-as="json" should take care of that. That is the way is done in the Polycast by Rob, one of the Google developers at the Polymer team.

Comment: `response` is just a json object but `items` is expecting an array of json objects. Can you link the video?

Comment: In the video (5min 21s) you can see his JSON which contains an array of items. The objects are wrapped in { } and all the objects are wrapped in an array [ ]. You only have one item so you don't need to use a template to loop through an array. Remove the `<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}">` lines and replace `item` with `response`:

`<div>
   <p>{{response.list.main.temp}}</p>
   <p>{{response.city.name}}</p>
 </div>`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when working with Firebase and Polymer.
In this case it is good to inspect your data that you want to hand over to the dom-repeat.

Luckily it is quit simple to convert (in my case an object to an array)..

```
Object.values()
```

in other cases you may want to use..

```
Array.from()
```

You can read more about both methods in here:
[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

However, it is important to know that both ways are not support in Internet Explorer